# Excel Interop right to left document

Tags: c#, excel-interop, worksheet, direction

I created a new Excel file with C#.

When I open the document all the worksheets are align right to left.

How can I align the worksheet/workbook/window to display left to right grammatically?

Answer (score 11):

```
Sub leftToRight()
    Application.DefaultSheetDirection = xlLTR
    ActiveSheet.DisplayRightToLeft = False
End Sub
```

You can also change the setting through *Tools->Options->International*. Note that you need to set/unset the Checkbox "View current sheet right-to-left" to change currently open sheets.

Edit: Sorry I accidentally interpreted your question as VBA.

Here is a c# Solution:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Visible = true;
xlApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);  
Excel.Worksheet active = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveSheet;

xlApp.DefaultSheetDirection = (int)Excel.Constants.xlLTR; //or xlRTL
active.DisplayRightToLeft = false;
```

Comment: the only remark i must add is that my class don't contain a 'Constants' property or field. so i used the built in enum of the interop dll calld xlDirection

Answer (score 7):

I would like to introduce my implementation of this feature after i used marg concept and changed it to the right syntax for me:

```
public void SetWorksheetDirection(Application excel, bool isRTL)
{
    Worksheet active = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

    if (isRTL)
        excel.DefaultSheetDirection = (int)XlDirection.xlToRight;
    else
        excel.DefaultSheetDirection = (int)XlDirection.xlToLeft;

    active.DisplayRightToLeft = isRTL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to organize some of the columns, you could use a line like this:

```
oWS.Range["A1:B2000"].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants.xlLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this one time to change the default direction:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the Immediate window
- in the Immediate window type `Application.DefaultSheetDirection = xlLTR` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close the VBA editor
- create a new workbook to test it